# Meteor error while trying to serve app

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm working on an app using meteor and angular. It was working fine, but now when I try to start it, I get this:

```
 While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):


module.js:338:15: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-transform-runtime'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\ecmascript\0.4.1\plugin.compile-ecmascript.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\meteor-babel\node_modules\babel-preset-meteor\index.js:4:6)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.getDefaults
   (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\ecmascript\0.4.1\plugin.compile-ecmascript.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\meteor-babel\options.js:11:15)
   at Object.getDefaultOptions (packages/babel-compiler.js:42:29)
   at packages/babel-compiler.js:133:32
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at BabelCompiler.BCp.processFilesForTarget (packages/babel-compiler.js:99:14)


   While minifying app stylesheet:
   module.js:338:15: Cannot find module 'source-map-url'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\standard-minifier-css\1.0.4\plugin.minifyStdCSS.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\minifier-css\node_modules\meteor\minifier-css\node_modules\css-stringify\node_modules\css\node_modules\source-map-resolve\lib\source-map-resolve-node.js:4:24)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\standard-minifier-css\1.0.4\plugin.minifyStdCSS.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\minifier-css\node_modules\meteor\minifier-css\node_modules\css-stringify\node_modules\css\lib\stringify\source-map-support.js:8:24)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.module.exports
   (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\standard-minifier-css\1.0.4\plugin.minifyStdCSS.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\minifier-css\node_modules\meteor\minifier-css\node_modules\css-stringify\node_modules\css\lib\stringify\index.js:32:22)
   at packages/minifyStdCSS_plugin.js:95:33
   at CssToolsMinifier.processFilesForBundle (packages/minifyStdCSS_plugin.js:30:16)


   While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.windows.x86_32):
   module.js:338:15: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-transform-runtime'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\ecmascript\0.4.1\plugin.compile-ecmascript.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\meteor-babel\node_modules\babel-preset-meteor\index.js:4:6)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.getDefaults
   (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\ecmascript\0.4.1\plugin.compile-ecmascript.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\meteor\babel-compiler\node_modules\meteor-babel\options.js:11:15)
   at Object.getDefaultOptions (packages/babel-compiler.js:42:29)
   at packages/babel-compiler.js:133:32
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at BabelCompiler.BCp.processFilesForTarget (packages/babel-compiler.js:99:14)


=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I tried running another app, and it works fine, but this one doesn't.
I'm ruuning Meteor 1.3 on windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by updating to a 1.3.1 release after reading this issue comment https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6609#issuecomment-205016877

```
meteor update --release 1.3.1-rc.3
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're simply missing (at least) two modules:

- babel-plugin-transform-runtime
- source-map-url

Try installing them and retry...

Comment: I figure that! but I'm not using them (at least directly). all I did was do a meteor update and this problem occured.

Comment: Still you need them... For some reason (wrong dependencieds list for some of the packages you use, perhaps...), they were not automatically  installed...:-(

Comment: I tried adding them (meteor add ... ), but I get an error: no such package!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had the same issue but fixed it by downgrading my meteor version from 1.3.3.1 to 1.3.2.4. run command

> meteor update --release=METEOR@1.3.2.4

Although the process takes some good time to complete